# how to save powerpoint presentation as read only recommended

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When I save a Word document in Word 2010, I can go to Tools -> General Options on the save dialog to save the document as "read-only recommended" so that other people opening it will be prompted whether they really want to make changes when they open it.

The General Options window on Powerpoint 2010 is missing the checkbox word has. Is there another way to save Powerpoint presentations that has the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `File -> Info-> Protect Presentation` and select the option that best suits your needs. Based on your description, you need to select 'Mark as Final'.  Here's a screenshot that shows the location of the various tabs.

[image]